# What is a good approach on saving settings files to change background themes for example?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I have been doing some research and I can't find how it's done, I want to make an activity with settings and files for my app and those will change colors, dark theme, buttons etc.

Also I have some doubts on how should I apply those changes, first thing that comes in mind is onCreate but since that would need a reload what is a good way to do this for example changing font color to white and background to black for a dark theme option ?

Another doubt is on changing button positions. Let's say I want 4 buttons positions, I could make all those 4 buttons and set views to GONE but that looks like a bad idea in terms of performance no ? If it is a bad idea or is there a better way to do that ?

I have a recycler view loaded from a sqlite database.

I saw this documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences  But still have some doubts, lets say button position 1234  and dark theme true/false.

How should I store one boolean and one Int in separated files? Or I should store a single text file read it and load it into my app like 1t for position 1 and dark theme true ?

I want to work on a very complete settings activity for my app.

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: SharedPreferences is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Androidx setting activity solved my problem since it already comes with shared preferences.

You can acces the preferences and use if to load different layouts or you can try to use some themes but all I found about themes was they were outdated.

to deal with preferences outside settings activity

```
open

val preference = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val layoutType =  preference.getInt("layout_type", 0)

edit 

val preference = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = preference.edit()
val layoutType =  preference.getInt("layout_type", 0)
editor.putInt("layout_type",0)
editor.apply()
```

about androidx activity

val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

and use keys inside root_preferences.xml

booleanbla = prefs.getBoolean("some_key", false)

If u have any doubts leave a comment ill edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

read up on `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` as one way of changing themes and colors dynamically, based on the time of day for the user (day mode/night mode). I think you are over-complicating the problem a bit as well, simply create different layout files and styles for the different screens you want to show and then use them as you need them, instead of trying to do everything with one file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! How do I inflate after the user pressed the button to change the style ? Maybe force to reaload on create or something ?

Comment: @AndreAndriole you would simply call  `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94 for more info, sorry i forgot to attach this initially

Comment: Ah thx, but i asked this because I also want to make more themes other than default, night and baterry saver. Well I will try to implement this to see how it works and maybe could use to other themes too.

Answer (score 1):

Create different styles for different "themes" you want.

Here's an example of how you can create different themes in a "settings" page and change it in real time. 
https://github.com/RoudyK/DemoApp

Basically the settings fragment is a preference fragment and each string maps to a style enum which references one of the styles defines in xml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I am trying to run this app but it looks complicated. After downloading/building it still didnt work, say it needs android studio 3.5 maybe i will need to doanload the beta :S

Comment: Hey Andre, the app is quite complicated true, but all you need to do is open "app" module and check the SettingsFragment. And yes I believe you need latest version of Android Studio to run.